# Avoid explicit title line break in acmart generated reference format

Tags: line-breaking, acmart

I'm writing a paper with the acmart format and I need to change the way title is broken up into two lines (because by default only 1 work "All" is on the second line which is ugly). But when I put an explicit line break with `\\` it is also propagated into the generated section called *ACM Reference format:*. Can I somehow avoid the line break in the "reference format"?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `\\` to enforce a line-break between words you want to go on *different* lines, you can use the protected whitespace `~` between the words you want to be on the *same* line.

So instead of:

```
\title{A very long title that challenges\\ ACM's LaTeX Layout}
```

write:

```
\title{A very long title that challenges ACM's~LaTeX~Layout}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in the whitespace being removed from the PDF's metadata. If you look at the properties of the PDF file (or the window title, in some PDF viewers), your example would give a title of `A very long title that challenges ACM'sLaTeXLayout`. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @FWDekker Now, 6.5 years later, I have trouble reproducing the problem. Can you provide a minimal .tex file that shows the original problem (e.g. as a link to a GitHub Gist)?

Comment: After some more experimenting, it appears you're right. The issue I had specifically only occurs when you add `\DocumentMetadata{}` before loading the class, which is required when you use acmart 1.90a (used by a conference I'm submitting to). But with the latest version you don't need that line, and `~` works normally in the PDF title. So your answer is all good, sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```
\title[A very long title that challenges ACM's LaTeX Layout]{A very long title that challenges\\ ACM's LaTeX Layout}
```